# When we enter bit.ly on url box how bitly.com open

Tags: dns, webserver, redirection, url, web

I have a question about how bitly.com to bit.ly work. My questions is not about shorting url from a long url to short one. Like the service Bitly provide.

Suppose I have website with the domain name freely.com and I want to access my website by tying free.ly in the url box. So, what setting I do in DNS field or something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is often done with a web redirect. That is, the web server at e.g. `free.ly` would be setup to pass any requests it receives along to ex. `freely.com`.

For DNS, the other method that might accomplish this goal is to use a CNAME record (though the `freely.com` web server would still need to be configured to handle requests it received for `free.ly`).

*Non-DNS (Web Redirect) Method Examples*

1. Independently set up the DNS for `freely.com` and `free.ly` to point to the proper web server(s).
2. Setup the web server(s) for `freely.com` and `free.ly`, respectively (i.e. so that the server recognizes it's own domain name(s)).

Configure the web server software under `free.ly` to redirect to `freely.com`:

3A. Apache (Virtual Host)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName free.ly
    Redirect / http://freely.com
</VirtualHost>
```

3B. Nginx (Server Block)

```
server {
        . . . 
        server_name free.ly;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://freely.com/$1 permanent; 
         . . . 
}
```

3C. HTML Meta Refresh (`free.ly` Landing Page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Meta Refresh Redirect</title>
        <meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "0; url = https://freely.com" />
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose I have website with the domain name freely.com and I want to
>   access my website by tying free.ly in the url box. So, what setting I
>   do in DNS field or something else.

According to what I understand from this paragraph, you want to type free.ly and it will actually present freely.com in the url box?

There are a few cases, but you should know that free.ly is a separate domain name and you need to purchase a .ly domain as well, not only just freely.com. If you only have the freely.com domain and expect there is a way to configure when you type “free.ly” onto address box and it will show freely.com. It doesn’t work that way.

By that, you can use multiple ways to redirect free.ly to freely.com by using CNAME in DNS entries, or use htaccess with 301 redirect, or even use two domain names that work together.

Firstly, purchase free.ly. After that, go to DNS record and add a new CNAME record with value is: freely.com.

The purpose is to redirect free.ly to freely.com when there is a request.